# proxy not working and port still goes port 3000 in react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, proxy

I want to fetch my data from port 8000,but it still get error 404.
Because it uses port 3000 ,I set proxy in package.json.
I don't know the reason why it goes wrong.

Error below:
*GET http://localhost:3000/hotels/countByCity?cities=berlin,madrid,lodon 404 (Not Found)*

Here are my relative codes:
pacakge.json

```
{
  "name": "booking",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy":"http://localhost:8000/api"
}
```

useFetch.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        setData(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  const reFetch = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url);
      setData(res.data);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return { data, loading, error, reFetch };
};

export default useFetch;
```

featured.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import "./featured.css"
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch"
const Featured = () => {
const{ data,loading,error}=useFetch("/hotels/countByCity?cities=berlin,madrid,lodon")
console.log(data);
    return (
        <div className='featured'>
            <div className="featuredItem">
                <img className='featuredImg' src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/53/47/6a/53476a9ce987dcc41b19385744f09ab3.jpg" />
                <div className="featureTitle">
                    <h1>Amazônia.</h1>
                    <h3>189 properties</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="featuredItem">
                <img className='featuredImg' src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/cf/fb/34/cffb34899bc7e9262f4f91270d51677d.jpg" />
                <div className="featureTitle">
                    <h1>Avignon’s historic center.</h1>
                    <h3>259 properties</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="featuredItem">
                <img className='featuredImg' src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/7f/6f/0a/7f6f0a8668aa2da61d9025859406e2f1.jpg" />
                <div className="featureTitle">
                    <h1>Naz City Hotel Taksim</h1>
                    <h3>345 properties</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Featured
```

Comment: "Keep in mind that proxy only has effect in development (with `npm start`), and it is up to you to ensure that URLs like `/api/todos` point to the right thing in production. You don’t have to use the `/api` prefix. Any unrecognized request without a `text/html` accept header will be redirected to the specified proxy." [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

Comment: @Samathingamajig You mean proxy should be "http:localhost:8000" or else?

Comment: Sorry,I am not the mother tounge in English.

Comment: The proxy should just be `http://localhost:8000` without the `/api`, and the `/api` should be included in your requests manually (like `useFetch("/api/hotels/countByCity?cities=berlin,madrid,lodon")`. Also, the proxy from `create-react-app` only runs in development mode, not production mode